# EKS and IRSA temporary credentials duration validity

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, boto3, amazon-eks

I am facing a challenge with my EKS cluster and IRSA.

I have created a service account in K8 associated with an AWS role, via the `eksctl create iamserviceaccount..` command. After that, I have modified the **maximum session duration** of the role in the AWS console, setting it to 12 hours.

I then used said service account in my deployment. Everything looks good once the workload runs in the cluster and my pod is able to assume the associated AWS role.

Whenever the pod executes an action that requires IAM auth, boto3 issues a `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` call and a set of temporary credentials are returned by AWS IAM (point 4 and 5 in the diagram below, source https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/diving-into-iam-roles-for-service-accounts/). These credentials (by looking in CloudTrail) last 1 hour, and this is in line with the default duration_seconds for such call (see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html).

[image: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/diving-into-iam-roles-for-service-accounts/]

I want those credentials to last more than 1 hour, I'd like for those to last 12 hours. The only way to achieve so, as far as I understood, is to specify `durations_seconds` in the $HOME/.aws/config file within the pod. After implementing that and testing again, I saw that the temporary credentials still last 1 hour. At this point, I have no idea how to change the duration behaviour. Has anyone ever encountered this situation? If yes, how was this solved?

Note: The OIDC JWT token lasts 24 hours, as I specified in the annotation `eks.amazonaws.com/token-expiration: 86400`

Thanks!
Alessio

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to this situation, but 1 hour is a hard coded max for an assume role from an assumed role, regardless of what you set expiration to. Without any configuration, the SDKs including boto3 should handle these expirations seamlessly. You do not need to manually call `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`.

Comment: Hey @jordanm no manual call here was made to AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity. I was just trying to line out the auth flow here.